# Continuously send UDP packets in background in Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sockets, udp

I want to send the data like button states, joystick values, etc from my app to a server repeatedly through UDP protocol to control a drone, I searched and tried the infinite while loop approach but it makes my app crash. I do not have much knowledge about working, I just want a Client that sends a string/JSON object continuously in the background as a datagram to defined IP and port. Any code snippets of the client or suggestions are welcome. Thank you.
Currently using Asynctask, but someone told me it's deprecated and not suitable. The code is given below. (reposting)

```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class UDP_Client {
    public String Message;
    @SuppressLint({"NewApi", "StaticFieldLeak"})
    public void sendUDP() {
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> async_cient = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){
                try (DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket()) {
                    DatagramPacket dp;
                    dp = new DatagramPacket(Message.getBytes(), Message.length(), InetAddress.getByName("192.168.***.***"), 3000);
                    ds.setBroadcast(true);
                    ds.send(dp);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }
        };
        async_cient.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it in a while true (infinite loop) in a separate thread within my main activity. And it works just fine!

```
new Thread( new Runnable() { @Override public void run() {
        while(true) {
            // Execute if mainSwitch is "ON"
            if(mainSwitchOn[0]) {
                // Creating new UDP_Client class object and accessing the public message variable to send data through
                // sendUDP() function
                Intent i = getIntent();
                String IpAddr = i.getStringExtra("IpAddr");

                UDP_Client Client = new UDP_Client();
                Client.Message = output;
                Client.IpAddress = IpAddr;
                Client.sendUDP();
                try {
                    // Giving 2ms sleep time to update values in thread.
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    } } ).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it on background. You need to use service.

Comment: I just want to send the data continuously, can't it be achieved by an infinite loop or anything simple? (please elaborate upon it)

Comment: You can try it with socket.